# Why Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Relational.dll causes error in one PC, and not in another PC?

Tags: .net, nuget, entity-framework-core

We have this ASP.NET Core MVC project, that uses EF Core.
We've hosted our project directly in IIS, so that we connect to it via IIS rather than Kestrel or IIS Express.

When we build the project, all of the compiled libraries go to `bin\Debug\netcoreapp2.0\` folder.

`Microsoft.EntityFramework` dll files are not copied there.

However on one machine the hosted site in IIS works just fine, while in another machine we get `502.5` error and when we see log files of `stdout` we see that it complains that `Microsoft.EntityFramework.Relational.dll` can not be found.

What Environmental difference might exist between these two PCs that causes this error?

Right now to solve this issue, we need to manually copy required EF Core dll files to that `netcoreapp2.0` folder on those machines that don't work, which is very tedious and incorrect.

We don't know how to make a Nuget package globally available (like GAC) and how to make it *copy to output* or stuff like that. Can you help us please?